# How to use Ninject across assemblies

Tags: c#, ninject

I can see that similar questions has been asked previously, but being totally new to DI and .Net I am not able to grasps the entire solution or may not have found the right source....

- I have assemblies WebAPI,BL,DL.
- WebAPI is dependent on BL,
- BL is dependent on DL,
- WebAPI DOES NOT reference DL and I would like to keep it the same. There are few more assemblies but this is sufficient to illustrates the issues.

WebAPI has application start section therefore I can use it to initialize the Ninject Kernel and register dependencies for WebAPI project.

How could I achieve the same for BL and other assemblies?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of different ways, you can use the [Ninject Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/What-is-configuration-by-convention) to automagically resolve every `ISomething` to an implementation that has the same name (e.g. `IThing` -> `Thing`) or you can create a [Ninject Module](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel) in each assembly which registers the dependencies (the module in your BL could load the module in your DL).

The approach you take would depend on whether you need to define different scopes for different objects, for example if you wanted some things resolved as singletons that may affect which method you use.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, I understand the concept but don't know how and where to implement the logic in the BL Assembly.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how each module sets up the kernel for Ninject? I'm trying to learn how to solve this problem too.

Comment: @Wavel - I've added links to the answer.

Comment: @user1767363 - I'm not sure exactly what you mean.. If you use Ninject Modules, just create a module in the BL assembly which you then load in the WebApi assembly where you create the Ninject Kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Mark Seemann's advice about this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) is great -- make a composition root at the highest possible layer of your application.  For Web apps, this means in the Globals.asax file.  I could expound on the good reason's for this, but the linked blog post does a better job.

This does break the layering you are trying to achieve, but only barely, and what I think is an appropriate way.  If your web layer is appropriately thin (i.e., you could replace it with a thick client fairly easily) then it isn't a big loss. If you are really adverse to that, you could create a composition root in the BL for the DL.